# Segmentation error while compiling c code with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int main()
{
  long array[1000], *maximum, size, c, location = 1;

  printf("Enter the number of elements in array\n");
  scanf("%ld", &size);

  printf("Enter %ld integers\n", size);

  for ( c = 0 ; c < size ; c++ )
    scanf("%ld", &array[c]);

   maximum  = array;
  *maximum = *array;

  for (c = 1; c < size; c++)
  {
    if (*(array+c) > *maximum)
    {
       *maximum = *(array+c);
       location = c+1;
    }
  }

  printf("Maximum element is present at location number %ld and it's value is %ld.\n", location, *maximum);
  return 0;
}
```

In this code to find the maximum number in an array,without the 'maximum  = array' ,i'm getting segmentation fault.What could be the reason?

Comment: Seg fault when *compiling*?  Then submit a compiler bug.  I think it's more likely that you have a fault when you run the compiled code; then you should run it under Valgrind to see where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maximum` is defined as a pointer to `long`.  If you don't set that pointer to point to something, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by reading and dereferencing an invalid pointer.

Also, because you point `maximum` to the first element of the array, anytime you update `*maximum` you're changing the first value in the array, which is probably not what you want.

There's really no need for `maximum` to be a pointer, so change the definition to `long` and change the references accordingly.

```
int main()
{
  long array[1000], maximum, size, c, location = 1;

  printf("Enter the number of elements in array\n");
  scanf("%ld", &size);

  printf("Enter %ld integers\n", size);

  for ( c = 0 ; c < size ; c++ )
    scanf("%ld", &array[c]);

   maximum = array[0];

  for (c = 1; c < size; c++)
  {
    if (array[c]) > maximum)
    {
       maximum = array[c]);
       location = c+1;
    }
  }

  printf("Maximum element is present at location number %ld and it's value is %ld.\n", location, maximum);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Maximum is an invalid pointer because it's datatype is not defined?

Comment: @Combospirit The datatype is defined, otherwise it wouldn't compile.  Without `maximum  = array;` it's invalid because it doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: Oh okay.So if the array were  an integer, it would be something like, maximum=&array to dereference it.Is that right?

Comment: @Combospirit That's assigning, not dereferencing (i.e. using `*` to get the value stored at a pointer), and that wouldn't work because the types are not compatible.  As is, `maximum` has type `long *` but `&array` has type `long (*)[1000]`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a segmentation fault is because you trying to de-reference a `NULL` pointer in when `maximum` is not set.

The correct way is (as mentioned in your code):

```
   maximum  = array;  // set the pointer to 'array'
  *maximum = *array;  // then de-reference.
```

Comment: As `maximum` is an automatic variable, it is not necessarily a null pointer, but its value is unspecified and it is UB to de-reference it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: This is true for un-optimized code. Compile at `-Os` will make it null.

Comment: OP has not specified the compilation options, and they are not specified in your answer either ;-). What I say is that the standard says *If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
indeterminate*. Indeterminate allows compilers to provide a well known value in that case as extentions.